# Windows links files with related extensions

Tags: windows-explorer

Windows 7 - if a folder contains two files with same name and different extensions (related extensions such as jpg & jpeg) then operations on one file ( rename or move) affect BOTH files at once

Very confusing "Feature"

example:
Files 101.jpeg and 101.jpg exist in a folder
Right click on 101.jpeg change name to 102.jpeg 
and surprise 101.jpg has also been renamed 102.jpg

Is there any way to get windows to not "link" them?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this on any version of Windows I have a VM for.

Comment: After further review, this happens when they are renamed in Irfanview - Sorry for the bad question